# "No module named tldextract"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-newspaper

I tried the following **code in python**:

```
from newspaper import Article

#A new article from BBC
url = "http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-26935867"

#For different language newspaper refer above table
BBC_article = Article(url, language="en") # en for English
```

And I am getting following **errors**:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "news_paper_article.py",
>   line 3, in 
>       from newspaper import Article
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper/**init**.py",
>   line 10, in 
>       from .article import Article, ArticleException
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper/article.py",
>   line 12, in 
>       from . import images   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper/images.py",
>   line 21, in 
>       from . import urls
>
> File
>   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newspaper/urls.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from tldextract import tldextract ImportError: No module named tldextract

It may be simple issues but I am just starting, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try with:

```
pip install tldextract
```

Comment: Thank you floatingpurr. This helped, but now I have the following error. "No module named lxml.etree". When I tried "pip install lxml.etree", it gave me "Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement lxml.etree"

Comment: You are welcome. Please, open another post to discuss a different issue.

Comment: yes and it is not working and giving the same error.

Comment: What did you type exactly? Which Python are you using?

Comment: I typed "pip install lxml", my version is Python 2.7.9

Comment: `pip install lxml` works fine here. What is your error?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install python3-tldextract
```

Comment: Is using `apt` preferable to `pip`?